# How to redirect to next page in Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

```
 index.hbs

    <h1> {{LoginTitle}} </h1>
      <form action="/login" method="post">
       <label for="Email">Email</label>
         <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
        <label for="password">password</label>
         <input type="text" name="password" id="password 
            placeholder="password">
         <input type ="button" value="SignIn"  onClick="'/welcome'">
        </form>
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('index', { LoginTitle: 'HOUSEHOLD EXPENSE' });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('welcome', { welcome : 'hey' });
});

router.post('/login', function(req,res,next){
if(req.body.Email == Email && req.body.password == password){
    res.render('welcome');
 }
 else
 {
  res.render('/');
  }

  });

  module.exports = router;
```

welcome.hbs

```
  <h1> {{ welcome }}</h1>

  <p> Hello Mr User</p>
```

I am using express handlebars.After successful logging in it is not going to next page welcome.hbs Can anyone let me know what mistake I am doing

Answer (score 0):

```
if(req.body.Email == Email && req.body.password == password){
res.render('welcome');
}
```

should be something like

```
if(req.body.Email == Email && req.body.password == password){
res.render('welcome', { welcome : 'hey' });
}
```

In index.hbs

```
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
<input type ="submit" value="SignIn">
```

Comment: :What about the router.get,is something required to change there too??

Comment: i dont see where router.get('/login'... will be used. Changing it didn't work?

Comment: @BeastLesnar check with new changes

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { LoginTitle: 'HOUSEHOLD EXPENSE' });
});

route.get('/welcome', function(req, res) {
    res.render('welcome', {welcome: 'Hey'});
}

router.post('/login', function(req,res,next){
    if(req.body.Email == Email && req.body.password == password){
         res.redirect('/welcome'); // Redirect to /welcome if success
    }
    else {
         res.redirect('/login'); // Redirect to /login if login fail
    }

});

module.exports = router;
```